# In Google search results comments can count as answers

Tags: discussion, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google doesn't know how to count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115634/google-doesnt-know-how-to-count)

When a question with no answers - that does have comments - appears in Google search results, the comments can appear to count as answers.  I was disappointed first time I saw one of these - it seems like poor 'management of expectations'.

Example:

[image: Google search result]

But the 4 "answers" are *comments* on the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654833/how-to-find-a-jndi-resource-inside-the-hibernatetool-ant-task) and there are *no* answers:

[image: SO question 654833]

I've seen other similar unanswered questions appear to have answers in Google search results.

As Google is a (the?) primary interface to SE, is this a problem?
If so, is there a Google Batphone to call?

Comment: Well that seems undesirable. I wonder if Google is scraping or API'ing...