# Google search results say question is answered when it has only a comment

Tags: bug, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Google search results comments can count as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137787/in-google-search-results-comments-can-count-as-answers)

When looking at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85391/29478) on [`Arquade`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), I Googled the question in the hope of finding an answer.

What I found was this listing on Google for the same question I was just on:

[image: Google listing]

It says them that there is 1 answer on the post.  There isn't actually any answer on the post, just a comment.

[image: Question page screenshot]

This could possibly be because there was an answer before that was deleted and Google hadn't updated since.  I however do not know whether there was previously an answer on that question so I can't tell.