# Google thinks my deleted question had 5 answers that I never saw...?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google doesn't know how to count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115634/google-doesnt-know-how-to-count)

One of my questions seems to have disappeared (presumably deleted?). When I googled it to try and see why it was gone, I noticed that google's summary of the page says there are 5 answers to the question, but I wasn't notified about them or the question being deleted. What's going on here?

I believe It's question 11130565. For now, the first hit on google for "git - gitolite ports (freeBSD) install - Stack Overflow" shows what I'm talking about.

Comment: [No there are no answers there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130565/gitolite-ports-freebsd-install). Only some comments. And you replied last so must have seen them all. Not sure where Google extracts the "5 answers" from.

Comment: @Pekka Ah didn't come across that one in my pre-ask search. This question is about my specific question though, while the other is about google's issue in general.

Comment: Your question was "autodeleted" see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year for more info.

Comment: @MatthewAdams - The answer there answers your question though. It has no answer so Google counts number of comments up to a max of 5.

Comment: @MartinSmith OK, so should I delete this question then?

Comment: @nemesv I see- that's fair, thanks for looking that up.

Comment: Humorously, I got distracted from the project that prompted the deleted question because of a burgeoning SO addiction...

Answer (score 1):

Google is wrong. (Cue shocked intakes of breath!) For example, Google claims that [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7235826/7872) has five answers, it only has two (none showing as deleted).

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130565/7872) appears to have no answers at all associated with it. It also appears that you were responsible for deleting it (as it doesn't indicate that it was deleted by others!). IF that is the case, you should be able to follow the link and click "undelete".

Note that it was only deleted **3 hours** ago, perhaps inadvertently?

Comment: Following the link just gives me the 404 page...

Comment: Odd - I thought everyone could see their own deleted questions... :/

Comment: Questions deleted by their author show the author name. This isn't the case here.

Comment: +1 for **Google is wrong**, I didnt know that part.

Comment: @Lucifer, it ocasionally warrants saying. Usually to the same people that claim that "it's on Wikipedia, it must be true!" ;-)

Comment: @Rob The question was deleted automatically since it's negatively scored, has no answers, and is over 30 days old.