# "Save this answer" text in Google search result

Tags: bug, google, seo, saves

The new save functionality seems to put the text "Save this answer." into Google's search results:

[image: Google search results for "sql do bit fields use an entire byte"]

It's a very minor thing. But probably not desired, right? It's not relevant to the answer as Google is trying to pull it out.

Comment: If anyone wants to repro, [here's a direct link](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+do+bit+fields+use+an+entire+byte+columns). I added the word "columns" because without it, Google was picking the second answer for me and didn't include the "Save this answer" text in the snippet.

Comment: Possibly related: [Bug: Google search result entry cites a closed question's closure reason as "Top answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115496/348196), [Google shows number of question bookmarks (formerly, favorites) in SO search result](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342226/8967612), [Google search result actually spells out the input controls of Stack Overflow. Is this Google's fault or bug in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334116/8967612) -- Based on these posts (and others), it looks like this isn't something SE would (could?) fix.

Comment: Might be useful if clicking the "Save this answer" on the Google result will actually add the answer to your Saves, automagically.